# создание SDN приложение с контроллером Floodlight

Tags: java-8

Здравствуйте, я  студентка и мне нужна помощь. Я работаю над создание SDN приложение с контроллером Floodlight. Проблема в создании таблиц для свитчей. А именно , как определять какие есть пути в сети для заданных 2х хостов, достать с этих путей номера свичей и портов и передавать это функции flowcreator.

```js
package net.floodlightcontroller.HA_app;

import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;

import org.projectfloodlight.openflow.protocol.OFFactories;
import org.projectfloodlight.openflow.protocol.OFFactory;
import org.projectfloodlight.openflow.protocol.OFFlowAdd;
import org.projectfloodlight.openflow.protocol.OFMessage;
import org.projectfloodlight.openflow.protocol.OFPortDesc;
import org.projectfloodlight.openflow.protocol.OFType;
import org.projectfloodlight.openflow.protocol.OFVersion;
import org.projectfloodlight.openflow.protocol.action.OFAction;
import org.projectfloodlight.openflow.protocol.action.OFActionOutput;
import org.projectfloodlight.openflow.protocol.instruction.OFInstruction;
import org.projectfloodlight.openflow.protocol.instruction.OFInstructionApplyActions;
import org.projectfloodlight.openflow.protocol.match.Match;
import org.projectfloodlight.openflow.protocol.match.MatchField;
import org.projectfloodlight.openflow.types.DatapathId;
import org.projectfloodlight.openflow.types.EthType;
import org.projectfloodlight.openflow.types.IPv4Address;
import org.projectfloodlight.openflow.types.IPv6Address;
import org.projectfloodlight.openflow.types.IpProtocol;
import org.projectfloodlight.openflow.types.MacAddress;
import org.projectfloodlight.openflow.types.OFBufferId;
import org.projectfloodlight.openflow.types.OFPort;
import org.projectfloodlight.openflow.types.TransportPort;
import org.projectfloodlight.openflow.types.U64;
import org.projectfloodlight.openflow.types.VlanVid;
import net.floodlightcontroller.routing.Path;
import net.floodlightcontroller.routing.PathId;
import net.floodlightcontroller.routing.IRoutingService;

import net.floodlightcontroller.core.IFloodlightProviderService;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentSkipListSet;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;


import net.floodlightcontroller.core.FloodlightContext;
import net.floodlightcontroller.core.IOFMessageListener;
import net.floodlightcontroller.core.IOFSwitch;
import net.floodlightcontroller.core.IOFSwitchListener;
import net.floodlightcontroller.core.PortChangeType;
import net.floodlightcontroller.core.internal.IOFSwitchService;
import net.floodlightcontroller.core.module.FloodlightModuleContext;
import net.floodlightcontroller.core.module.FloodlightModuleException;
import net.floodlightcontroller.core.module.IFloodlightModule;
import net.floodlightcontroller.core.module.IFloodlightService;

import net.floodlightcontroller.devicemanager.IDevice;
import net.floodlightcontroller.devicemanager.IDeviceService;
import net.floodlightcontroller.devicemanager.SwitchPort;

import net.floodlightcontroller.packet.Ethernet;
import net.floodlightcontroller.packet.IPv4;
import net.floodlightcontroller.packet.TCP;
import net.floodlightcontroller.packet.UDP;

public class HA_App implements IFloodlightModule, IOFMessageListener, IOFSwitchListener {

  protected IFloodlightProviderService floodlightProvider;
  protected Set < Long > macAddresses;
  protected static Logger logger;
  protected IOFSwitchService switchService;
  protected IRoutingService routingService;
  protected IDeviceService deviceService;
  // more flow-mod defaults
  public static final long FLOW_COOKIE = 0x5555;
  protected static short FLOWMOD_DEFAULT_IDLE_TIMEOUT = 0; // in seconds
  protected static short FLOWMOD_DEFAULT_HARD_TIMEOUT = 0; // infinite
  protected static short FLOWMOD_PRIORITY = 101;
  public HashMap < String, ArrayList < String >> extractedData;
  public HashMap < String, ArrayList < String >> pathID;

  @Override
  public String getName() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return HA_App.class.getSimpleName();
  }

  @Override
  public boolean isCallbackOrderingPrereq(OFType type, String name) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean isCallbackOrderingPostreq(OFType type, String name) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
  }

  @Override
  public void switchAdded(DatapathId switchId) {
    if (switchId.toString() == "4a:fc:f9:9c:f0:47") {
      flowCreator(OFPort.of(3), OFPort.of(1), switchId);
      flowCreator(OFPort.of(2), OFPort.of(1), switchId);
    } else if (switchId.toString() == "8a:f1:36:48:fb:44") {
      flowCreator(OFPort.of(2), OFPort.of(1), switchId);
    } else if (switchId.toString() == "d2:f4:54:8a:9f:40") {
      flowCreator(OFPort.of(2), OFPort.of(1), switchId);
    } else if (switchId.toString() == "1a:15:fa:f5:c5:40") {
      flowCreator(OFPort.of(2), OFPort.of(2), switchId);
    } else if (switchId.toString() == " a2:51:46:de:1b:4c") {
      flowCreator(OFPort.of(2), OFPort.of(1), switchId);
    } else if (switchId.toString() == "ae:e7:b4:3f:40:4a") {
      flowCreator(OFPort.of(3), OFPort.of(0), switchId);
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void switchRemoved(DatapathId switchId) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

  }

  @Override
  public void switchActivated(DatapathId switchId) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  }
  @Override
  public void switchPortChanged(DatapathId switchId, OFPortDesc port, PortChangeType type) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

  }

  @Override
  public void switchChanged(DatapathId switchId) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

  }

  @Override
  public void switchDeactivated(DatapathId switchId) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

  }

  @Override
  public net.floodlightcontroller.core.IListener.Command receive(IOFSwitch sw, OFMessage msg, FloodlightContext cntx) {
    switch (msg.getType()) {
      case PACKET_IN:

        /* Retrieve the deserialized packet in message */
        Ethernet eth = IFloodlightProviderService.bcStore.get(cntx, IFloodlightProviderService.CONTEXT_PI_PAYLOAD);

        /* Various getters and setters are exposed in Ethernet */
        MacAddress srcMac = eth.getSourceMACAddress();
        MacAddress dstMac = eth.getDestinationMACAddress();
        System.out.println(dstMac.toString());
        System.out.println(srcMac.toString());
        VlanVid vlanId = VlanVid.ofVlan(eth.getVlanID());
        // Get attachment points
        ArrayList < String > apSrc = getAttachmentPoints(srcMac);
        ArrayList < String > apDst = getAttachmentPoints(dstMac);


        // Get attachment points

        /* Check the ethertype of the Ethernet frame and retrieve the appropriate payload.
         * Note the shallow equality check. EthType caches and reuses instances for valid types.
         */
        if (eth.getEtherType() == EthType.IPv4) {
          /* We got an IPv4 packet; get the payload from Ethernet */
          IPv4 ipv4 = (IPv4) eth.getPayload();


          /* 
           * Check the IP protocol version of the IPv4 packet's payload.
           */
          if (ipv4.getProtocol() == IpProtocol.TCP) {
            /* We got a TCP packet; get the payload from IPv4 */
            TCP tcp = (TCP) ipv4.getPayload();

            /* Various getters and setters are exposed in TCP */
            TransportPort srcPort = tcp.getSourcePort();
            TransportPort dstPort = tcp.getDestinationPort();
            short flags = tcp.getFlags();

            /* Your logic here! */
          } else if (ipv4.getProtocol() == IpProtocol.UDP) {
            /* We got a UDP packet; get the payload from IPv4 */
            UDP udp = (UDP) ipv4.getPayload();

            /* Various getters and setters are exposed in UDP */
            TransportPort srcPort = udp.getSourcePort();
            TransportPort dstPort = udp.getDestinationPort();

            /* Your logic here! */
          }

        } else {
          /* Unhandled ethertype */
        }
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
    return Command.CONTINUE;
  }

  public ArrayList < String > getAttachmentPoints(MacAddress mac) {
    ArrayList < String > list = new ArrayList < > ();
    IDevice device = deviceService.findDevice(
      MacAddress.of(mac.getBytes()),
      VlanVid.ZERO, IPv4Address.NONE,
      IPv6Address.NONE,
      DatapathId.NONE,
      OFPort.ZERO);

    if (device != null) {
      SwitchPort[] attachmentPoints = device.getAttachmentPoints();
      for (SwitchPort sp: attachmentPoints) {
        OFPort devPort = sp.getPortId();
        DatapathId devNode = sp.getNodeId();
        list.add(0, devNode.toString());
        list.add(1, devPort.toString());
        //System.out.println(" Switch ID: "+ sp.getPortId());
        System.out.println(mac.toString() + " hello " + sp.toString());
        break;
      }
    }
    return list;
  }
  public Path getPath(ArrayList < String > listEndNodes) {
    Path shortestPath = routingService.getPath(
      DatapathId.of(listEndNodes.get(0)),
      OFPort.of(Integer.parseInt(listEndNodes.get(1))),
      DatapathId.of(listEndNodes.get(0)),
      OFPort.of(Integer.parseInt(listEndNodes.get(1))));
    return shortestPath;
  }



  public synchronized HashMap < String, ArrayList < String >> getExtractedDataTable() {
    return extractedData;
  }

  public synchronized HashMap < String, ArrayList < String >> getPathIDTable() {
    return pathID;
  }

  public void flowCreator(OFPort port, OFPort port2, DatapathId switchId) {
    /* Creating a Flow for specific  OFPort
     * Returns Flow
     */
    IOFSwitch sw = switchService.getSwitch(switchId);
    ArrayList < OFAction > actionsList = new ArrayList < OFAction > ();
    ArrayList < OFInstruction > instructionsList = new ArrayList < OFInstruction > ();
    OFFactory factory = OFFactories.getFactory(OFVersion.OF_13);
    //OFFactory myFactory = OFFactories.getFactory(OFVersion.OF_13);
    Match forward = factory.buildMatch()
      .setExact(MatchField.ETH_TYPE, EthType.IPv4)
      .setExact(MatchField.IP_PROTO, IpProtocol.TCP) //TCP Protocol
      .setExact(MatchField.IPV4_SRC, IPv4Address.of("192.168.1.11"))
      .setExact(MatchField.IPV4_DST, IPv4Address.of("192.168.1.12"))
      .build();

    Match backward = factory.buildMatch()
      .setExact(MatchField.ETH_TYPE, EthType.IPv4)
      .setExact(MatchField.IP_PROTO, IpProtocol.TCP)
      .setExact(MatchField.IPV4_SRC, IPv4Address.of("192.168.1.11"))
      .setExact(MatchField.IPV4_DST, IPv4Address.of("192.168.1.12"))
      .build();


    OFActionOutput output = factory.actions().buildOutput()
      .setPort(port)
      .setMaxLen(0xffFFffFF)
      .build();

    actionsList.add(output);

    OFActionOutput output2 = factory.actions().buildOutput()
      .setPort(port2)
      .setMaxLen(0xffFFffFF)
      .build();

    actionsList.add(output2);


    OFInstructionApplyActions applyActions = factory.instructions().buildApplyActions()
      .setActions(actionsList)
      .build();

    instructionsList.add(applyActions);

    OFFlowAdd flow = factory.buildFlowAdd()
      .setMatch(forward)
      .setCookie((U64.of(HA_App.FLOW_COOKIE)))
      .setIdleTimeout(HA_App.FLOWMOD_DEFAULT_IDLE_TIMEOUT)
      .setHardTimeout(HA_App.FLOWMOD_DEFAULT_HARD_TIMEOUT)
      .setPriority(HA_App.FLOWMOD_PRIORITY)
      .setBufferId(OFBufferId.NO_BUFFER)
      .setInstructions(instructionsList)
      .build();
    OFFlowAdd flow2 = factory.buildFlowAdd()
      .setMatch(backward)
      .setCookie((U64.of(HA_App.FLOW_COOKIE)))
      .setIdleTimeout(HA_App.FLOWMOD_DEFAULT_IDLE_TIMEOUT)
      .setHardTimeout(HA_App.FLOWMOD_DEFAULT_HARD_TIMEOUT)
      .setPriority(HA_App.FLOWMOD_PRIORITY)
      .setBufferId(OFBufferId.NO_BUFFER)
      .setInstructions(instructionsList)
      .build();

    sw.write(flow);
    sw.write(flow2);
  }


  @Override
  public Collection < Class << ? extends IFloodlightService >> getModuleServices() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
  }

  @Override
  public Map < Class << ? extends IFloodlightService > , IFloodlightService > getServiceImpls() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
  }

  @Override
  public Collection < Class << ? extends IFloodlightService >> getModuleDependencies() {
    Collection < Class << ? extends IFloodlightService >> l =
      new ArrayList < Class << ? extends IFloodlightService >> ();
    l.add(IFloodlightProviderService.class);
    l.add(IOFSwitchService.class);
    l.add(IDeviceService.class);
    l.add(IRoutingService.class);
    return l;
  }


  @Override
  public void init(FloodlightModuleContext context) throws FloodlightModuleException {
    floodlightProvider = context.getServiceImpl(IFloodlightProviderService.class);
    macAddresses = new ConcurrentSkipListSet < Long > ();
    logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HA_App.class);
    deviceService = context.getServiceImpl(IDeviceService.class);
    routingService = context.getServiceImpl(IRoutingService.class);
    switchService = context.getServiceImpl(IOFSwitchService.class);
    extractedData = new HashMap < String, ArrayList < String >> ();
    pathID = new HashMap < String, ArrayList < String >> ();
  }

  @Override
  public void startUp(FloodlightModuleContext context) throws FloodlightModuleException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    floodlightProvider.addOFMessageListener(OFType.PACKET_IN, this);
    switchService.addOFSwitchListener(this);
  }

}
```

Comment: Вы покажите как делаете, а мы постараемся сказать, что не так

Comment: I added code ...